# Get current number of pages with filter apllied

Tags: category, filter, pagination

I need to get the current number of pages (if we are in a category) in head.phtml. 
The line below doesn't help me because if a filter is applied, the total of pages must to change.

```
$prodCol = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in' => array(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG, Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)));
$tool = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager')->setLimit($this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar')->getLimit())->setCollection($prodCol);
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current page number form url of that page.

Try below code

```
<?php Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('p')?>
```

For eg :

```
http://localhost/magento/index.php/shop.html?p=4
```

here get parameter "p" is the current page number of the pagination

Comment: I'm affraid that doesn't help me, maybe my question is not well formed . I need to get the total number of pages.